# Deleting Desktop Background Images

Tags: terminal, finder

I want to free up some space on my hard drive by deleting things and I found that 2GB were being used just on desktop backgrounds. I don't particularly care what my desktop background is so I'd like to delete these files.

Unfortunately, no matter what I try, I can't seem to delete these files.

Things I've tried:

- `sudo rm ./*`
- deleting them through finder
- `chflags nouchg location/nameoffile.extension` - i.e. unlocking the file
- giving Terminal Full Disk Access

How can I delete these files?

Thanks,

**Update:** My version of macOS is 10.15.3

Comment: Without knowing the exact version of macOS you're running, I'd assume you are running into SIP protections.  Restart into Recovery Mode, open Terminal, and enter: `csrutil disable` then `reboot` the Mac.

Comment: `sudo rm ./*` is very dangerous. Make sure you're in the correct directory. Then make sure again. BTW, where are these desktop backgrounds stored?

Comment: @lhf they're in /System/Library/Desktop Pictures

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I think I've figured it out. This was the recipe that worked:

### Delete the Files

- Reboot into recovery mode
- Open the Terminal from the "Utilities" menu
- `csrutil disable` as suggested by da4 (thanks!)
- Reboot
- `mount -uw /` i.e. mount the filesystem as writable
- `sudo rm -r "/System/Library/Desktop Pictures"/*`

### Restore System Integrity Protection

- Reboot into recovery mode again
- Open the Terminal from the "Utilities" menu
- `csrutil enable`
- Reboot

Comment: Aren't there any subfolders? There is a `Solid Colors` subfolder in High Sierra.

Comment: I figure if they've made it this far they'll be able to figure out the rest :)

Comment: Let's play safe :-)

Comment: There is absolutely no need to go through all of this rigmarole to achieve the goal! Simply boot to **macOS Recovery** and in **Terminal** from there, run, e.g., `rm -r "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/Desktop Pictures"/*` and then reboot.

Comment: @user3439894 Nice, way easier. So what's the best practice here, since that's fairly different from the current answer? Should I add an edit with that as the new proposed solution on top of the old solution? Completely replace the current answer? Thanks.